# display empty records in an ASP.Net GridView?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How can I display 10 empty records in a GridView from code-behind Page_Load?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new `DataTable` in the `Page_Load` event that has 10 empty rows of data in it, then bind that to your `GridView`.